# strange Firebase IOS queryStartingAtValue returns wrong order

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, lazy-loading

im trying to implement a collectionview that present posts with lazy loading, loading only 15 posts at a time,im saving the last downloaded post in a variable `lastPostID` and pass it to the method `queryStartingAtValue` but when i get the results, the `snapshot.value` is sorted properly but when i do write this line:

```
NSDictionary *retrivedData = snapshot.value;
```

the `retrivedData` dictionary gets messed up and the order is wrong. and because of that im keep getting same result for every different query because the `lastPostID` is always the same

thats my query code:

```
  FIRDatabaseReference *dbRef = [[[[FIRDatabase database]reference] child:POSTS_FOR_CHALLENGES] child:challengeID];    
    [[[[dbRef queryOrderedByKey]  queryStartingAtValue:lastPostID] queryLimitedToFirst:15] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            //sort the keys of the dictionary/json alphabetically
            NSMutableDictionary *posts = snapshot.value;
            if(sortedValues.count > 0)
            {

                lastPostID = [snapshot.value allKeys].lastObject
            }
            [connector postsForChallengeRetrived:posts];

        }];
```

i managed to solve it by sorting the `retrivedData`'s keys at the client side but its not a good solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `snapshot` contains the ordered results. But when you request `snapshot.value` it converts the results into a dictionary, which is inherently unordered.

So instead of immediately converting to a dictionary, [loop over `snapshot.children`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+ios+snapshot.children) and you'll find them in the correct order.